# $x+x^2e^{-x}$ uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

How can i show that the function $f(x)=x+x^2e^{-x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$,

If I choose $x,y\in[0,\infty)$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|x+x^2e^{-x}-y-y^2e^{-y}|\leq ?$  I am stuck here please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x$ is uniformly continuous on the real line, and since the sum of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous, it suffices to show that $$f(x)=x^2e^{-x}$$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$. This function behaves nicely: It is *monotone* over two intervals $[0,M],[M,\infty)$ where $M$ is the point where $f$ attains its maximum, goes to $0$ in $\infty$ and $=0$ at the origin.

Find it's maximum and it's range. How far can $f(x)$ be from $f(y)$? We can even take a step forward. Find $f'$. Use the MVT to find a **fixed** constant for which $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|$$

for any pair $x,y\in \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: so infact it is a Lipschitz function !

Comment: @Mathematician Yes, good. Over $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Mathematician Whenever you say "it is Lipschitz" remember you have to say "over $D$" where $D$ is some domain. In this case, $f$ is not Lipschitz over the real line, for example, but is Lipschitz on any bounded subset.

Comment: yes ofcourse this is what i meant